# Capture video frames with opencv in android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I am trying to process android video in real time with opencv-android. So far I am able to access the video with opencv, and display it on a `org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView`.(I referred to [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html)) I haven't been able to access the video feed of the camera by frame-wise. I need to get each and every frame in order to apply some opencv algorithms on them for object tracking. Please suggest a method to access and process the frames with opencv. (Redirect this if it's already been asked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
 public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    //Do your processing here, for example:
    Mat image = inputFrame.rgba();
    Mat ret_mat=new Mat();
    Core.add(image, new Scalar(40, 40, 40, 0), ret_mat); //change brightness of video frame

    return ret_mat;
}
```

OpenCv functions operate with Mat object, which represents matrix of pixels of your image/frame. The code above makes each frame brighter by 40 units.

Comment: But how do I get the 'CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame' in the first place to pass it as an argument? Does 'CameraBridgeViewBase' provide any methods to get the frame from it?

Comment: This is the method you have to Override. See point 11. in the link you provided. Your Activity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2. Here is my complete code: http://pastebin.com/DT9PtfCY

Comment: I edited my comment, see complete working Activity code and do not forget to mark my answer useful if it solves your problem.

Comment: Can we convert a stored mp4/avi video to frames and can use that instead of camera frame with OnCameraFrame();